# Can someone explain how to solve L1 regularized logistic regression step-by-step?

Tags: regression, logistic, lasso, regularization

All those online courses that mention logistic regression with regularization explain the L2 regularization. This makes sense because L2 has a derivation-based analytical solution, which leads to, in updating the coefficients, just reducing them by a factor (proportional to the penalty parameter), and it is very intuitive. However, I need to figure out how to solve the L1 as well. There are implementations, but what I want is the mathematical steps that lead to this implementation. There is [this paper](http://www.andrewng.org/portfolio/efficient-l1-regularized-logistic-regression/) which proposes an efficient solution to it, but the math there is too complex. Can someone just explain the simplest way to solve it? No need for algorithmic efficiency for now.

Comment: Not an answer, though you may be inteterested in this vignette of the glmnet algorithm for R, which includes L1, L2 and elastic net regularization: https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html The problem is being solved using warm-start gradient descent methods (multiple descents using previous results as starting points). All other explanations are the details of how warm-start works and which gradient descent methods are suitable.